# SQLConnection code

Tags: c#, sql

When trying to establish a connection I get the exception below:

```
System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException occurred
  HResult=0x80131904
  Message=Login failed for user ''.
  Source=.Net SqlClient Data Provider
  StackTrace:
<Cannot evaluate the exception stack trace>
```

I keep getting the above error, here is my code:

```
SqlConnection conn = 
  new SqlConnection(@"Data Source = Computer-DELL\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog = Drivers");

conn.open();
```

Comment: What about entering a user ID and password, or trusted connection?

Comment: Duplicate that will do: https://stackoverflow.com/q/14567939/993547

Answer (score 2):

Your connection string does not have Username and Password  and or Integrated Security.

With Integrated Security:

```
Data Source=localhost\SQLSERVER;Initial Catalog=YourDataBaseName;Integrated Security=True;
```

With username and password:

```
Data Source=localhost\SQLSERVER;Initial Catalog=YourDataBaseName;persist security info=True;user id=someusername;password=somepassword;
```

Comment: If it is local and they have rights use the integrated security if its easier.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming they have permission, local user:

```
SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source = Computer-DELL\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog = Drivers;Trusted_Connection=True;")
conn.open();
```